# Clearing set<set<T> > in C++ STL

Tags: c++, parsing, stl, set

I was working on a program that generates the FOLLOW of each variable in LL(1) Parsing and my implementation is based on the fact that variables that have the same FOLLOW should be in the same set.

So, I start off with a set of set of characters that looks something like this -
{ {E}, {B}, {T}, {Y}, {F} }

Suppose, I get E and B to have the same follow, the procedure must be to modify the original set to -

{ {E,B}, {T}, {Y}, {F} }

For this purpose, I chose the Data structure as std :: set < std :: set < char> >

Here's my code snippet for a subroutine that involves the deletion of the other sets (In the given instance, I aim at deleting {B} after performing union {E,B}

```
set<set<char>> similarSets;
void findSET(char ch)
{
    set<set<char>>::iterator it1;
    set<char>::iterator it2;
    for (it1 = similarSets.begin(); it1 != similarSets.end(); it1++)
    {
       // (*it1).clear();
       // the above line doesn't seem to work

    }
}
```

Comment: Please be more specific than "doesn't seem to work".

Comment: A `std::set`s elements are immutable. You might want to look at the "set" operations in `<algorithm>`.

Comment: With this data structure, you'd have to erase `{E}` and `{B}`, and then insert `{E,B}`